# Alter column from varchar to decimal when nulls exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I alter a sql varchar column to a decimal column when there are nulls in the data?

I thought:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN data decimal(19,6)
```

But I just get an error, I assume because of the nulls:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric. The statement has been terminated.
```

So I thought to remove the nulls I could just set them to zero:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN data decimal(19,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

but I dont seem to have the correct syntax.

Whats the best way to convert this column?

*edit*
People have suggested it's not the nulls that are causing me the problem, but non-numeric data. Is there an easy way to find the non-numeric data and either disregard it, or highlight it so I can correct it.

Comment: You are getting the error because you have values that cannot be converted to decimal, not because of nulls. What version of SQL-Server are you using? If you are using SQL-Server 2012 or later you can make use of the [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function. If you add a new column, update it using your old values and try_convert, then you will be able to identify the problem values, where your decimal column is null and your varchar column is not.

Comment: I'd *strongly* suspect that it's not the nulls that are a problem. This: `create table T (one varchar(20))
insert into T(one) values ('1.5'),(null)
alter table T alter column one decimal(5,2)` runs without error.

Comment: Hmmmmm I see. This could be fun then going through the data and finding the errant entry, there are 1000's of rows

Comment: You can use something like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(data) = 0` to help identify the records, but [`ISNUMERIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) has its issues, so this may not catch everything. Or if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, a better solution would be `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE data IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,6), data) IS NULL`

Comment: Found out what my problem was, my varchar was a varchar(8) and I was trying to convert it to a decimal(19,6). By converting to a decimal(8,4) instead everything works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were just the presence of NULLs, I would just opt for doing this before the `alter column`:

```
update table1 set data = '0' where data is null
```

That would ensure all nulls are gone and you could successfully convert.

---

However, I wouldn't be *too* certain of your assumption. It seems to me that your new column is perfectly capable of handling NULL values since you haven't specified `not null` for it.

What *I'd* be looking for is values that *aren't* NULL but also aren't something you could turn in to a real numeric value, such as what you get if you do:

```
insert into table1 (data) values ('paxdiablo is good-looking')
```

though some may argue that should be treated a 0, a false-y value :-)

The presence of non-NULL, non-numeric data seems *far* more likely to be causing your specific issue here.

---

As to how to solve that, you're going to need a `where` clause that can recognise whether a `varchar` column is a valid numeric value and, if not, change it to `'0'` or `NULL`, depending on your needs.

I'm not sure if SQL Server has regex support but, if so, that'd be the first avenue I'd investigate.

Alternatively, provided you understand the limitations <sup>(a)</sup>, you could use [`isnumeric()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) with something like:

```
update table1 set data = NULL where isnumeric(data) = 0
```

This will force all non-numeric values to NULL before you try to convert the column type.

And, please, for the love of whatever deities you believe in, back up your data before attempting any of these operations.

If none of those above solutions work, it may be worth adding a brand new column and populating bit by bit. In other words set it to NULL to start with, and then find a *series* of updates that will copy `data` to this new column.

Once you're happy that all data has been copied, you should then have a series of updates you can run in a single transaction if you want to do the conversion in one fell swoop. Drop the new column and then do the whole lot in a single operation:

- create new column;
- perform all updates to copy data;
- drop old column;
- rename new column to old name.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> From the linked page:

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).

Comment: Spoke too soon!
update table1 set data = NULL 
where isnumeric(data) = 0

ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN data decimal(19,6)

Gives same error

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    data VARCHAR(100)
)

GO

INSERT INTO  test VALUES ('19.01');
INSERT INTO  test VALUES ('23.41');

ALTER TABLE test ADD data_new decimal(19,6)
GO

UPDATE test SET data_new = CAST(data AS decimal(19,6));

ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN data
GO

EXEC sp_RENAME 'test.data_new' , 'data', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: The update query: `UPDATE test SET data_new = CAST(data AS decimal(19,6));` will still fail if there are values that cannot be converted to decimal. This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, that error doesn't come from nulls, it comes from varchar values that can't be converted to decimal. Most typical reason for this I've found (after checking that the column doesn't contain any logically false values, like non-digit characters or double comma values) is when your varchar values use comma for decimal pointer, as opposed to period.

For instance, if you run the following:

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(256)
SET @T = '5,6'
SELECT @T, CAST(@T AS DEC(32,2))
```

You will get an error.

Instead:

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(256)
SET @T = '5,6'

-- Let's change the comma to a period
SELECT @T = REPLACE(@T,',','.')

SELECT @T, CAST(@T AS DEC(32,2)) -- Now it works!
```

Should be easy enough to look if your column has these cases, and run the appropriate update before your ALTER COLUMN, if this is the cause.

You could also just use a similar idea and make a regex search on the column for all values that don't match digit / digit+'.'+digit criteria, but i suck with regex so someone else can help with that. :)

Also, the american system uses weird separators like the number '123100.5', which would appear as '123,100.5', so in those cases you might want to just replace the commas with empty strings and try then?